# Negation, Contrapositive of (¬a ∧ b) → c

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Need to find the negation and contrapositive of (¬a ∧ b) → c

Negation of  ¬a∧b,  using De Morgan’s law is  a∨¬b. and the negation of an implication is the conjunction of its antecedent and the negation of its consequent.

So am I correct in understanding the negation of  (¬a ∧ b)→ c  is  ¬a ∧ b ∧ ¬ c.

and the contrapositive of  (¬a ∧ b)→ c  =  ¬c→(a∨¬b).

Similarly, for the statement "If it is raining then I will bring my umbrella."

Are the following correct?
Negation: If it is not raining then I will not bring my umbrella.
Contrapositive: If I do not bring my umbrella, then it is not raining

Comment: Yes, this all looks correct.

Comment: They are all correct **except** the negation of the umbrella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of “If it is raining, then I will bring my umbrella” is not “If is not raining, then I will not bring my umbrella.”  The latter is equivalent to the **converse** of the former.

In symbols,
$$
\neg(p \rightarrow q) = \neg((\neg p) \lor q) = p \land \neg q
$$
while
$$
(\neg p) \rightarrow (\neg q) = (\neg(\neg p)) \lor (\neg q) =  (\neg q) \lor p = q \rightarrow p
$$

Back into words, the negation of “If it is raining, then I will bring my umbrella” is “It is raining and I won't bring my umbrella.”